# C/C++ open-source library to convert RTF to PDF

Tags: open-source, library, c++, c, document-converter

I need an open-source C/C++ library that would help me convert RTF document to PDF.

I have searched and the only two available solutions I have found so far are:

1. `Librtf` is a C-style library with no documentation at all [official page](http://librtf.sourceforge.net/#Documentation)
2. `UnRTF` is a command-line programm that converts RTF file to HTML with lots of bugs as well [official page](http://www.gnu.org/software/unrtf/unrtf.html#downloading)

Any ideas / thoughts / suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `ghostscript` https://www.ghostscript.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use [LibreOffice in headless mode](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters), for example:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf file_name.rtf
```

Or use it as [service](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/sag47-492023/headless-file-conversion-using-libreoffice-as-a-service-35310/), in conjunction with [`unoconv`](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv).

Comment: ... but can LO be used as a library, rather than as a binary? (I mean, other than writing a library which forks libreoffice)